Remote Desktop Error upon starting WSL Ubuntu 24.04
I have just installed Ubuntu 24.04 on a brand new computer running Windows 11 Home.  As soon as the distro launches via wsl (and even immediately after install), I receive multiple of the following popups

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall Ubuntu and the issue persists.

What version of WSL are you using?  If it's WSL2, do you have virtualization enabled in your BIOS/UEFI?

It is WSL 2 - I'm on a Surface Laptop Studio 2, so virtualization is enabled by default, at least according to everything I'm reading.
